# Axes label outside plot without Frame

Tags: graphics

I'd like to draw a plot with the $x$ and $y$ axes labeled outside the plot and along the axes (with $y$ axis rotated)--not at the end of each axis--as in this *Matlab* plot.  Moreover, I do not want to use a Frame.

[image]

(Ignore the ***Title***.)

Comment: does `Plot[x, {x, 0, 1}, 
 FrameLabel -> {{"y-Label", None}, {"x-Label", None}}, 
 Frame -> {{True, False}, {True, False}}]` give what you need?

Comment: @kglr:  Yep... that's it.  (How did I not find that on my own!?!)

Comment: also `Labeled[Plot[x, {x, 0, 1}], {"x-Label", "y-Label"}, {Bottom, Left}, 
 RotateLabel -> True]`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can mimic a plot without a frame using `Frame -> {{True, False}, {True, False}}`:

```
Plot[x, {x, 0, 1}, 
 FrameLabel -> {{"y-Label", None}, {"x-Label", None}}, 
 Frame -> {{True, False}, {True, False}}]
```

[image]

You can also use `Labeled`:

```
Labeled[Plot[x, {x, 0, 1}], 
 {"x-Label", "y-Label"}, 
 {Bottom, Left}, 
 RotateLabel -> True]
```

[image]